# Tree sorting function in Scheme

Tags: sorting, tree, scheme, racket

Im struggling with this problem for over 2 days now and still somehow I cannot solve it.
I have to write a function in SCHEME that takes a list in a tree and displays items in sorted order.

The way I define trees is '(6 (left... ) (right...))

My function to choose a tree:

```
(define (tree-sort tree)
 (cond  ((null? tree) '())
    ((> (car tree) (cadr tree))
     (tree-sort (cadr tree)))
    (else
     (tree-sort (caddr tree))))
)
```

So I guess I should also have a function that sorts the most indepth list?
I really dont get it and this is the last time I will ever have to deal with scheme. I have never used stackoverflow so please excuse me if the formating is wrong.

Kindly thank you!

Comment: Is the tree sorted? I mean - when you insert an element in the tree, you ensure that all the elements less than the current value in a node go to the left, and all the elements greater than it go to the right?

Comment: Yes, the tree is sorted. I forgot to specify that.

Comment: Notice that this is not a "tree sorting" function, the tree is already sorted. What you want to do is traversing it in such a way that the elements in the traversal are sorted. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you clarified that the tree is already sorted, then you're looking for an [in-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_.28symmetric.29) traversal of the tree, which returns a sorted list of the elements - I'm assuming that you're interested in a *list* as the output, because of the base case shown in the question. Try something like this:

```
(define (tree-sort tree)
  (if (empty-tree? tree)
      '()
      (append (tree-sort (left-subtree tree))
              (list (value tree))
              (tree-sort (right-subtree tree)))))
```

Use the appropriate procedures for testing if the tree is empty and for accessing each node's value, left and right subtrees. The above procedure will return a sorted list with the trees' values.